# USB Powerbank for Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: usb-power

Is it yet feasible to use a USB powerbank to power the Raspberry Pi 4B? Are there any that you've successfully tried and could recommend? Can a 2.4A USB-C bank work?

Answer (score 8):

The [Raspberry Pi 4 spec](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/) recommends a **3 A supply (15 W)**, with a minimum current of 2.5 A if downstream USB peripherals consume less than 500 mA in total.

Furthermore [the MagPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/raspberry-pi-4-specs-benchmarks/) benchmarks a power draw under load of 7.6 W "running a CPU-intensive benchmark while an HDMI display and a USB keyboard and mouse are connected" (note that they do not state the use of any on-board peripherals, such as GB-Ethernet, WiFi, or BLE). 7.6 W at 5 V is a current of 1.52 A.

[image]

Considering the data listed above it seems rather likely that a Pi 4 can be powered with a solid 2.4 A power bank (if no additional power hungry peripherals are connected) even though it is below the *recommended ratings*.

Answer (score 3):

I am running a pi4 with v2 noir from an old 10.000 powerbank.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended current requirement for Pi4B is 3A, so 2.4A power bank is rather not enough, and the pi could be unstable on such power supply. You need a powerbank that can supply at least 3.0A, then it will be perfectly fine for powering up the Pi4B.

Comment: That is not the minimum requirement, it is recommended if you want to power the PI and some USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

On the official raspberry pi power cord, it shows a 3A⎓5V sign, so I think any power bank with 3 amps and 5 volts would work, just make sure to save work and shutdown the raspberry pi before the power bank runs out, or you could lose your work and/or have the microSD card corrupted. (I want to make a portable raspberry pi 400 desktop setup)