# Can I supply power with 5V 2Amp to Raspberry pi 4

Tags: power-supply, pi-4

Can I supply power with 5V 2Amp to Raspberry pi 4? Currently 5V 3Amp chargers by Raspberry Pi are out of stock , so I am using phone charger with 5V 2Amp along with Type C adapter.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Please pay some attention to tags - they serve a purpose. Please do not just tag your questions with ill-fitting tags. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The Pi4B reportedly needs about 1.5 amps under load (see this [Magpi chart](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100107/19949)).  Thanks to Ghanima for that link

You only need more if you have power hungry peripherals which need powering through the Pi.

Comment: If we are to believe the MagPi's benchmark ([here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100107/19949)) it'd be roughly 1.5 A under load.

Comment: I didn't know that, and have no reason to doubt it so will correct my answer.

Comment: Watch the red power led on the Pi. If if blinks or goes out, you don't have enough power. By default, the red led is a 'power ok' indicator.